# Store id from database query in cookie

Tags: database, cookies

I need to store an ID value which is generated upon doing a database insert. After the insert, javascript redirects the user to an external page, which will then redirect back to a wordpress page (within the same theme).

But I can't just set a cookie after the database query, since the page is already loaded.

So I tried to create an init-action which should set the id from the latest query into the cookie:

```
function set_memberid_cookie() {

 global $wpdb;
             setcookie(
                 'member_id',
                 $wpdb->insert_id,
                 time() + 86000,
                 COOKIEPATH,
                 COOKIE_DOMAIN
             );
        }

add_action( 'init', 'set_memberid_cookie');
```

Apparently this doesn't work, because it seems that the latest "insert_id" will be lost when a new page has been loaded.

Somehow I need the value from the query to be standby to be added to a cookie when a new page is loaded. I hope there is a solution.

Comment: "javascript redirects the user to an external page" - can you just set the cookie via this javascript?

Comment: Do you mean with Ajax or something? Otherwise I guess I would run into the same problem. The cookie can only be set when there is a page reload.